# What's the function of these operators?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm wondering the function of these integral operators.
F.eg. **⨗** f(x)dx
What would I do when i find these operators in an equation?

*List:*
**⌠**, **⌡**, **⨍**, **⨎**, **⨗**, **⨘**, **⨙** and **⨚**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbols in mathematics rarely have a unique meaning. It is the case of the last 5 symbols you wrote, that is  ⨎, ⨗, ⨘, ⨙ and ⨚. I guess they are variants of the “o int” symbol $\oint$, which typically denotes integration along a closed contour, also known as “circuitation” in electromagnetism.

The barred integral ⨍ is different, it does have a common meaning in mathematics, it denotes the “integral average”
$$
\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\, dx, $$
and its higher-dimensional versions.

Comment: Does this mean the ⨏ operator has the same function as the ⨍ operator? Because as far as I know, the ⨏ integral is the "integral average" operator.

Comment: Yes, these are just different calligraphies.

Answer (score 2):

The first two symbols are only used in computer science to display integrals in a terminal. They don't have any mathematical meaning.